# WooCommerce archive-product.php template theme issue

Tags: wordpress, templates, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, woocommerce-theming

[current theme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/faOrq.png)
There is a fault of the theme view. I need to display this as [correct theme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rq7jf.png). Current code is archive-product.php

```
<?php
/**
 * The Template for displaying product archives, including the main shop page which is a post type archive
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/archive-product.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @package WooCommerce\Templates
 * @version 3.4.0
 */

defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;

get_header( 'shop' );?>

<!--breadcrumbs area start-->
<div class="breadcrumbs_area">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
                <div class="breadcrumb_content">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>">home</a></li>
                        <li>Shop</li>
                    </ul>
                    <!-- <button id="toggleFiltersBtn" class="toggle_filters_btn" style="float: right; margin-top: -28px; margin-right: 10px;">Show Filters</button> -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!--breadcrumbs area end-->





<article class="col">
    <h2 style="text-align:center;color:white;">Shop</h2><br>
</article>

<?php

/**
 * Hook: woocommerce_before_main_content.
 *
 * @hooked woocommerce_output_content_wrapper - 10 (outputs opening divs for the content)
 * @hooked woocommerce_breadcrumb - 20
 * @hooked WC_Structured_Data::generate_website_data() - 30
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content' );

?>
<header class="woocommerce-products-header">
    <?php if ( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_show_page_title', true ) ) : ?>
        <h1 class="woocommerce-products-header__title page-title"><?php woocommerce_page_title(); ?></h1>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php
    /**
     * Hook: woocommerce_archive_description.
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_taxonomy_archive_description - 10
     * @hooked woocommerce_product_archive_description - 10
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_archive_description' );
    ?>
</header>
<div class="shop_area mt-60 mb-60">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <?php
        /**
 * Hook: woocommerce_sidebar.
 *
 * @hooked woocommerce_get_sidebar - 10
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_sidebar' );?>
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="shop_toolbar_wrapper">
                    <div class="shop_toolbar_btn">

                        <button data-role="grid_3" type="button" class="btn-grid-3" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" title="3"></button>

                        <button data-role="grid_4" type="button" class="btn-grid-4 active" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" title="4"></button>

                        <button data-role="grid_list" type="button" class="btn-list" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" title="List"></button>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="page_amount"><?php
                    /**
     * Hook: woocommerce_before_shop_loop.
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_output_all_notices - 10
     * @hooked woocommerce_result_count - 20
     * @hooked woocommerce_catalog_ordering - 30
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop' );?>
                    </div>
                </div>
                

                <?php
if (woocommerce_product_loop()) {
    woocommerce_product_loop_start();

    if (wc_get_loop_prop('total')) {
        $loop_counter = 1;
        while (have_posts()) {
            the_post();

            /**
             * Hook: woocommerce_shop_loop.
             */
            do_action('woocommerce_shop_loop');

            // Custom HTML structure
            ?>
            <div class="row shop_wrapper">
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
                    <article class="single_product">
                        <figure>
                            <div class="product_thumb">
                                <a class="primary_img" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><img src="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>" alt=""></a>
                                <a class="secondary_img" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><img src="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>" alt=""></a>
                                <div class="label_product">
                                    <span class="label_sale">sale</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="action_links">
                                    <ul>
                                        <li class="wishlist"><a href="<?php echo esc_url(wc_get_account_endpoint_url('wishlist')); ?>" title="Add to Wishlist"><i class="fa fa-heart-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                                        <li class="compare"><a href="#" title="compare"><span class="ion-levels"></span></a></li>
                                        <li class="quick_button"><a href="#" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#modal_box" title="quick view"> <span class="ion-ios-search-strong"></span></a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                                <div class="add_to_cart">
                                    <?php
                                    if ($loop_counter === 1 && is_shop()) {
                                        woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart();
                                    }
                                    ?>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="product_content">
                                <div class="price_box">
                                    <?php
                                    /**
                                     * Hook: woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title.
                                     *
                                     * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_price - 10
                                     */
                                    do_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title');
                                    ?>
                                </div>
                                <div class="product_ratings">
                                    <?php
                                    /**
                                     * Hook: woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item.
                                     *
                                     * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_rating - 5
                                     */
                                    do_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item');
                                    ?>
                                </div>
                                <h3 class="product_name"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
                                <div class="product_desc">
                                    <p><?php echo wp_trim_words(get_the_excerpt(), 20, '...'); ?></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </figure>
                    </article>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php
            $loop_counter++;
        }
    }

    woocommerce_product_loop_end();

    /**
     * Hook: woocommerce_after_shop_loop.
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_pagination - 10
     */
    do_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop');
} else {
    /**
     * Hook: woocommerce_no_products_found.
     *
     * @hooked wc_no_products_found - 10
     */
    do_action('woocommerce_no_products_found');
}

/**
 * Hook: woocommerce_after_main_content.
 *
 * @hooked woocommerce_output_content_wrapper_end - 10 (outputs closing divs for the content)
 */
do_action('woocommerce_after_main_content');
?>



</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<?php
get_footer( 'shop' );
?>
```

Below Code is after get from browser developer mode elements

```
<ul class="products columns-3">
    <div class="row shop_wrapper">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
            <article class="single_product">
                <figure>
                    <div class="product_thumb">
                        .................
                    </div>
                    <div class="product_content">
                        .................
                    </div>
                </figure>
            </article>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row shop_wrapper">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
            <article class="single_product">
                <figure>
                    <div class="product_thumb">
                        ......................
                    <div class="product_content">
                        ......................
                    </div>
                </figure>
            </article>
        </div>
    </div>
</ul>
```

Below code is accurate code of this problem

```
<ul class="products columns-3">
    <div class="row shop_wrapper grid_4">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
            <article class="single_product">
                <figure>
                    <div class="product_thumb">
                        ..................
                    </div>
                    <div class="product_content">
                        ..................
                    </div>
                </figure>
            </article>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
            <article class="single_product">
                <figure>
                    <div class="product_thumb">
                        ...................
                    </div>
                    <div class="product_content">
                        ..................
                    </div>
                </figure>
            </article>
        </div>
    </div>
</ul>
```

I need to get this as correct user interface. How can get this. I am using woocommerce with third party user interface.